# Rails: UJS not executing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

I have some UJS that's meant to replace a partial in my view. The .js file looks like this:

```
transition("#content_container", "<%= escape_javascript(render 'users/show') %>");
librarySorter("User", "<%= @user.username %>");
```

The transition function executes as expected, but librarySorter isn't executing. I check in firebug, and it does appear in my response like so:

```
librarySorter("User", "tbaron");
```

And stranger yet, if I copy and paste that line into my firebug console, it runs properly and executes. I've been tinkering with this for hours, and I still have no idea why it's not working. Any ideas?

For reference, here's what librarySorter looks like (it's in application.js):

```
function librarySorter(library_type, id){
  function publication_sort_binder(type, order, name){
    $("#overview_table").animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
    $("#sort_method").html(type+' '+order);
    var url = library_type == "User" ? '/users/'+id+'/owned_publications' : '/groups/'+id+'/overview_sort'
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      data: {'function':type+' '+order},
      url: url,
      success: function() {
        $("#publication_sort_arrow").remove();
        var arrow = (order == 'ASC') ? '&darr;' : '&uarr;';
        $('#sort_'+name).unbind("click").click(function() {
          publication_sort_binder(type, (order == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC', name);
      }).append("<span id='publication_sort_arrow'> "+arrow+"</span>");
      }
    });
  }
  $('#sort_title').click(function() {
    publication_sort_binder("publications.title", "DESC", "title");
  })
  $('#sort_author').click(function() {
    publication_sort_binder("contributors.name", "DESC", "author");
  })
  $('#sort_review_date').click(function() {
    publication_sort_binder("reviews.created_at", "DESC", "review_date");
  })
  $('#sort_review_vote').click(function() {
    publication_sort_binder("reviews.votes_sum", "DESC", "review_vote");
  })
  $('#sort_children_total').click(function() {
    publication_sort_binder("updates.replies_count", "DESC", "children_total");
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't on the transaction function? It could be messing up your code.

Comment: When I run both the transition and librarySorter through the firebug console, I get no explicit errors. So my guess is no.

Comment: did you try running just that method or changing the order?

Comment: Unfortunately, librarySorter is contingent on transition. Transition renders the links "sort_children_total", "sort_review_vote", etc. Without them, librarySorter wouldn't have the necessary ids to hook onto.

Comment: Could it be a timing issue?  If `transition` has any async behavior, it could be that `librarySorter` is running before `librarySorter` has finished it's work.  maybe?